# Creating Django form with pictures

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

model.py

```
class Venue(models.Model):
venue_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
rent = models.IntegerField()
parking_area = models.IntegerField()
picture = model.ImageField(upload_to="image/");
```

I want to create a form that let the user select from the list of venues. I did create a normal form for this i cant get to load the picture in html

Answer (score 0):

you need to reference the url where the file is being stored.  you should be able to do this in your templates by

```
{{ myobject.picture.docfile.url }}
```

Comment: could you give me an example

Comment: I kind of thought I did.  I'll try to add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, use the following code:

```
<img alt="{{myobject.venue_name}} picture" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{my object.picture}}">
```

This is when the context object is called myobject

Comment: could sent me the view.py also i didnt understand